# beginContact not working despite physics working

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have a game using libGDX and box2D in which I use a ContactListener to detect collisions between entities and projectiles. For some reason, despite the physics moving the bodies due to the collision, my code is not causing the entity to die or register a hit at all. Putting the same code as I put in beginContact in preSolve seems to result in more of them colliding properly but not all. The entity is a dynamic body with bullet = true and the bullet itself is a kinematic body.
Here is the code for my contact listener:

```
public class CollisionManager implements ContactListener
{

    @Override
    public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold)
    {
        Object o1 = contact.getFixtureA().getBody().getUserData();
        Object o2 = contact.getFixtureB().getBody().getUserData();
        if (contact.isTouching())
        {
            if (o1 instanceof Entity && o2 instanceof Projectile)
            {
                collideBullet((Entity) o1, (Projectile) o2, contact);
            }
            else if (o1 instanceof Projectile && o2 instanceof Entity)
            {
                collideBullet((Entity) o2, (Projectile) o1, contact);
            }
        }
    }


    private void collideBullet(Entity entity, Projectile projectile, Contact contact)
    {
        if (entity instanceof Enemy && projectile.getOwner() instanceof Defence)
        {
            projectile.setCollided();
            entity.takeDamage(projectile.getDamage());
        }
        else if (entity instanceof Defence && projectile.getOwner() instanceof Enemy)
        {
            projectile.setCollided();
            entity.takeDamage(projectile.getDamage());
        }
        contact.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

And here is the code for takeDamage in case im an idiot.

```
    public void takeDamage(float damage)
    {
        this.health -= damage;
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            health = 0;
            setState(EntityState.DYING);
            body.setActive(false);
        }
    }
```

The entities all have one health and the bullets do 10 damage for testing purposes.

I have tried moving code to presolve instead of beginContact, I have poured through the docs but cannot find what is going wrong, I have tried turning the entity into a bullet, with no changes from that.